# In a proto3 message is there a way to mark a field as not required for requests and required for response?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I have the following proto3 message structure:

```
message BaseBuildContent {
  string locale = 1;
  string buildVersion = 2;
  string buildLabel = 3;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp createTime = 4;
}
```

I am using the "same" structure for some requests and responses on my app. What I want to achieve is to mark somehow (if possible) the createTime  field as not required, in case we are talking about a request object, and required in case we are taking about a response object.

Is it possible to do this without creating a separate message ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, it's not possible and I'd discourage pursuing solutions other than defining distinct message types: one which includes the optional field and one which does not.

One way to solve this is to define a message that includes the mandatory fields and another than extends it:

```proto
message BaseBuildContent {
  string locale = 1;
  string buildVersion = 2;
  string buildLabel = 3;
}

message SomeRequest {
  BaseBuildContent content = 1;
}

message SomeResponse {
  BaseBuildContent content = 1;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp createTime = 2;
}
```

> **NOTE** Protobuf style guide [recommends](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style#message_and_field_names) message names be `PascalCased` and field names be `snake_cased`.

Comment: I'm aware about the protobuf style guide recommendations, is just that I don't agree with them. I prefer to use camel case across the whole code stack in order to remove any type of confusions that might arise from having different naming conventions in different sections of the code.